# Including files from another folders in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, include

I've ordered a bit my structure of classes and moved the related ones to more specific folders. The problem is that now the includes I made are not being able to find the class, as right now is in another folder.

Why is it not looking automatically for the file through all the folders?

[image]

I shouldn't have to write #include "Gameplay/TestMap.hpp". How can I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't want to write `#include "Gameplay/TestMap.hpp"`

Comment: Because I never had to do it before, and I think I can avoid it.

Comment: Then you'll have to configure the directory Gameplay to be in the include path

Comment: that is what I'm looking for... how can I do it? I've already tried adding it into: Paths and Symbols page, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to add paths in eclipse [Help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm)

Comment: As I explained to you, I checked the Autodiscovery paths and also added the folders to the Paths and Symbols, and it still does not work.

Comment: Another option is to add the folder in gcc options, but that won't solve the problem you're having in eclipse :(

Comment: How can I do that? I'm going to get crazy. I tried many things and still it does not work.

Comment: In your compiler configuration, you should add -I/include/path/ to gcc options